# Picturecallback is never triggered in some devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-2.3-gingerbread

On click of capture button, first I start progressdialog then I am calling the PictureCallback. Inside the callback I dismiss the dialog. But the dialog is never dismissed and hence the callback is not triggered.

```
captureImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
                        mProgressDialog.show();
                    }
                    captureImageButton.setEnabled(false);

                    if (CameraConfigurationUtils.mCameraInstance != null) {
                        CameraConfigurationUtils.mCameraInstance.takePicture(null, null, mJPEGPictureCallback);
                    }
                }
            });


private Camera.PictureCallback mJPEGPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        CameraConfigurationUtils.releaseCamera();
        Log.e("DEBUG", "THis is picture call back");
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        ProcessImageAsyncTask processImageAsyncTask = new ProcessImageAsyncTask(CameraActivity.this);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            processImageAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, data);
        else
            processImageAsyncTask.execute(data);
    }
```

Comment: what does the dialog not getting dismissed have to do with the callback. the workflow does not stop when the dialog is shown your code continues even after calling `show` on the dialog

Comment: I have added my callback code. I am dismissing the dialog in the callback.

Comment: so maybe`CameraConfigurationUtils.mCameraInstance` is null for some reason

Comment: No that is not null. I debugged it.